# Why text.includes("") is true

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which contains objects.

```
let todos = [ {
    text: 'Order cat food',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'Clean Kitchen',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'Buy food',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'Do work',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'Exercise',
    completed: true
}]
```

I was making a todo application and I was experiencing unexpected result. I used the following code to understand what's happening and it's returning true .

```
todos.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element.text.includes(''))
});
```

So my Question is why is it returning true for empty strings?

Comment: Because every string contains an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

An empty string contains an empty string.
For that matter, all initialized strings contain an empty string. The clearest example for would be using `indexOf` like so `"".indexOf("")`.

Notice how `""` is the same on both sides.
Every string starts with `""`, on index 0.

Comment: This is just another example of the same thing. In the end OP just has to accept a) set theory and b) that programming is as "mathy" as it can be and implements methods such as `includes()`, which sees the string as a set, based on what set theory would do. That was a human decision, they could also have created a function that throws an error when it is told to find "nothing". Deriving the behavior from set theory in the end was an arbitrary (albeit useful, of course) decision, so at the end of the day OP just has to learn to accept that it is how it is and that's all there is to it.